# CSS scale() not working on Android Chrome 70 and other versions

Tags: android, css

I want to show a small colored dot in front of a price tag. The dot should be centered vertically next to the price and scaled up a bit.

This works on chrome desktop, iOS, Safari and others.

[image]

But on Android the dot is huge and takes up the entire space of the div.

[image]

```css
.item.green::before {
  content: "●";
  color: #7ED321;
}

.item {
  transform: scale(1.4);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

.priceText {
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="priceText">
  <span class="item green" style="" title="Verfügbarkeit"></span> 1.050&nbsp;€
</div>
```

How can I center the dot verically and make sure in Android it is shown with the scale factor provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a simple background instead where you can easily adjust the size and position.

You can also consider CSS variable to adjust the color:

```css
.priceText {
  padding-left: 15px;
  background:radial-gradient(var(--c,#7ED321) 4px,transparent 5px)  /*4px radius*/
    left center /*position*/
    /
    10px 10px /*size: must be at least 2xradius*/
    no-repeat;
}

.orange {
  --c:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="priceText">
   1.050&nbsp;€
</div>

<div class="priceText orange">
   1.050&nbsp;€
</div>
```

Another syntax:

```css
.priceText {
  padding-left: 15px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle at 5px 50%, var(--c,#7ED321) 4px,transparent 5px) 
    no-repeat;
}

.orange {
  --c:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="priceText">
   1.050&nbsp;€
</div>
<div class="priceText orange">
   1.050&nbsp;€
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one! How could the color be adjusted easily? Currently I am adding another class to the item: .item.orange::after {
  content: "●";
  color: #F5A623;
}

Comment: Wow! You've got me stunned. Guess you are on a complete different level. I never saw that --c markup. Is this CSS3? It seems to work on all browsers I tested so far.

Comment: @merlin yes it's CSS, you can read more about here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties ... it's well supported, you will only face issue on IE but I guess it's not a surprise ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query to control what happens when the screen size is scaled down to Android

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  .items {
    transform: scale(1.4);
  }
}
```